# Does this normal distribution plot show a good fit?

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, qq-plot

I am not well acquainted enough to judge this well. This plot was obtained from normplot in Matlab. There is a good linear fit although the tails are concerning. Does my data follow a normal distribution, judging from this?

[image]

Comment: This looks very consistent with the sample being drawn from a normal distribution. Though the tails do not match perfectly, this is within a tolerable range.

Comment: Tolerable range for what purpose? If I'm using the normal distribution to estimate $P(X>\mu+3.5\sigma)$ it looks like I would greatly overestimate the actual probability. If I was trying to build a CI for the mean it might be fine but the OP doesn't state they're doing anything of the kind.

Comment: Good point. I was presuming the latter.

Comment: Yes that's a good fit, if you look at the example in the help file the tails on the probplot just do that. It's worrisome if they are on the opposite side of the line.

Comment: @Dave, the tails are on opposite sides of the line.